# Have an element of the list clicked on load activity Monodroid

Tags: c#, xml, xamarin.android

I have a little problem. When I select an item from a list is selected and is colored, until everything is right. Then when I go to another activity and I come back I want the item in the list is selected again.
To summarize select an item in the list is reloaded when the activity, the ListView must know the item you want to click the loading for MonoDroid

Sorry for the bad English, I hope I explained.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The functionality you want is not normal behavior of Android, when the phone is in [Touch Mode](http://android-developers.blogspot.dk/2008/12/touch-mode.html) when and uses API level of less than 11.

So the easiest way is to target your application for API 11 or higher and add the following to your list item layout:

```
android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
```

You also have to set `ChoiceMode` on your list view:

```
listView.ChoiceMode = ChoiceMode.Single;
```

Now to remember the position of the item selected for when returning to the `ListView`you need to save it somewhere. So in the `ItemClick` event handler you could save the position to the `SharedPreferences` like so:

```
var prefs = GetPreferences (FileCreationMode.Append);
var editor = prefs.Edit();
editor.PutInt("ListViewSelectedItem", args.Position);
editor.Commit();
```

And to set the highlighted item when coming back to the Activity with the `ListView` you could place the following code in `OnResume`:

```
var prefs = GetPreferences(FileCreationMode.Append);
var val = prefs.GetInt("ListViewSelectedItem", 0);
listView.SetItemChecked(val, true);
```

Given that `listView` is accessible from the `OnResume` method.

Comment: Thank you!
I just wanted to ask one thing: